# angularjs routing and asp.net MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to remove # from angularjs default routing from an asp.net MVC project using html5

app.js

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
         .when('/', { templateUrl: '/home/index' })
         .when('/domain', { templateUrl: '/domain/index' })                        
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

My landing point is /Home/Spa

.net MVC routing:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                   "",
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
                   new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

     routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Default2",
      "{*url}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
      new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

      routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
        );
     routes.MapRoute("ShoppingCart",
                        "cart/",
                        new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Cart" },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

Everything works fine but sometimes i want to use Non Spa routing like  ShoppingCart (/cart), it always redirect back to Home due to .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });.

How can i make some exception rule in this case ?

Comment: what does it do if you remove the otherwise part?

Comment: it shows nothing in ngView

Comment: you can try to watch for a route change $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next) {), check the next route and apply window.location.href = next if it is a mvc route.

Comment: how I understand if it is a mvc route or not?